# PHP remove all HTML event attributes in an HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, domdocument, htmlpurifier

I would like to remove all event attributes (e.g. from all events based on [Event reference list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events)).

Is there a function in PHP's DOMDocument class that recognizes event attributes?

I tried using RegEx but it has gotten complicated with single quotes and double quotes:

```
preg_replace('/on*[a-z]+=".*?"/i', '', $html); // Doesn't match onclick="alert(\"hello\");"
```

I tried an external library called HTMLPurifier but it has no option to remove all event attributes.

Any idea what directions to take or a simple solution?

Comment: @Dagon I have a form that allows user to display their HTML of their article, but restrict them from using zero javascript: no script tags, no link tags and DEFINITELY no event attribute tags.

Comment: [Is this what you mean](http://ideone.com/6FsFa)

Comment: Whitelisting is safer than blacklisting.

Comment: that's unlikely to be enough protection from malicious users iframe\ embed the potential list is large

Comment: Not sure what the first `*` is for - you're teling it you're looking for things like `onnnnnclick` or even `oclick` - the `*` is only affecting the `n`.

Comment: With your current code, I can do this: `onClick='omghaxorz();'`

Comment: why not using PHP `filter_var()` ?  Remove  js event not solution.

Comment: @SamSquanch THAT WORKS! That function works.

Comment: @user1105430: Please use the DOM for that.

Comment: "_I tried an external library called HTMLPurifier but it has no option to remove all event attributes._" Not quite: It has no option to _keep_ them. It removes all malicious HTML by default, and for some unsafe HTML, you need to jump through hoops to get it to accept it regardless. (Don't misunderstand me, though - that's a _good_ thing.) I'd recommend giving it another try. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want truly secure code, a whitelist approach ('only allow these things: ...') is typically sturdier than a blacklist approach ('don't allow these things: ...').

You mentioned HTML Purifier and that "*it has no option to remove all event attributes*".

That's... technically correct, in that you can't *tell* it to remove event attributes. The reason is the selling point, though: It does that automatically. The option that's "missing" is an ability to configure HTML Purifier to *allow* event attributes. That's deliberately amiss. HTML Purifier (as the name suggests) has a strong security focus.

There are *some* 'unsafe HTML' aspects that you *can* allow using the HTML Purifier configuration (the default configuration is deliberately picky), but the event attributes are not amongst those. (Well, you could teach HTML Purifier to accept them if you jumped through hoops, but it would take a lot of effort.)

I'd recommend giving it another try if you want to accept user HTML. It's a fairly established tool that's been tested by a lot of people.

There are some very tricky ways to break HTML and inject JavaScript. For example, did you know that you can inject JavaScript using the `src` or `href` attribute? Did you know you can, in some browsers, inject JavaScript using the `style` tag? Take a look at [this XSS cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). It might give you a rough idea what you're up against, and why whitelisting is generally considered more efficient.

Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterText($value)
{
  if(!$value) return $value;

  return escapeJsEvent(removeScriptTag($value));

}

function escapeJsEvent($value){
  return preg_replace('/(<.+?)(?<=\s)on[a-z]+\s*=\s*(?:([\'"])(?!\2).+?\2|(?:\S+?\(.*?\)(?=[\s>])))(.*?>)/i', "$1 $3", $value);        
}

function removeScriptTag($text)
{
   $search = array("'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si",
         "'<iframe[^>]*?>.*?</iframe>'si");

  $replace = array('','');

  $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);

  return preg_replace_callback("'&#(\d+);'", function ($m) {
    return chr($m[1]);
  }, $text);
}


echo filterText('<img src=1 href=1 onerror="javascript:alert(1)"></img>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**A way to make it with the DOM.**

The following code seeks and removes attributes whose name starts by "on" in all html tags.

*(`$html` stands for the html code)*

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$onAttributes = $xpath->query("//*/@*[starts-with(name(), 'on')]");
foreach ($onAttributes as $onAttribute) {
    $onAttribute->ownerElement->removeAttributeNode($onAttribute);
}

$body = $xpath->query('body')->item(0);
$result = substr($doc->saveHTML($body),6,-7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the HTML document, iterate over all elements and then over all attributes of them (nested), remove attributes if they start with `on`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagname('*') as $element) 
{
    foreach (iterator_to_array($element->attributes) as $name => $attribute)
    {
        if (substr_compare($name, 'on', 0, 2, TRUE) === 0)
        {
            $element->removeAttribute($name);
        }
    }
}
```

You also might want to scrape the list of known attribute names and give a warning if an unknown one is found (or have a whitelist of attributes you allow). Hope this helps, the code is quickly typed to might have some little errors.

Comment: any reason for the iterator_to_array() ? i mean.. foreach is *meant* for iterators.